# Why do it says it never touches and has no parameters when one of the requirements is? [Kotlin]

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mocking, spring-webflux

The test below runs and the test is successful, but I don't understand why.

Clearly, `whatIWouldLikeToCapture` will run and give an `empty Flux` due to `privateMethod` what has a mocked content. But the interceptor says it doesn't run and there are no parameters.

Why `times(0)` in  `verify(mockedProvider, times(0)).whatIWouldLikeToCapture(captor.capture())`

```kotlin
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.mockito.BDDMockito.given
import org.mockito.kotlin.*

// ...

@MockBean
lateinit var mockedProvider: FooProvider

@MockBean
lateinit var mockedRepository: BarRepository

@Autowired
lateinit var provider: BazProvider
//...

@Test
fun testSave1() {
    val data = makeData();

    given(mockedProvider.whatIWouldLikeToCapture(any())).willReturn(Flux.empty())
    given(mockedProvider.method(any())).willReturn(Flux.empty())
    given(mockedRepository.save(any())).willReturn(Mono.just(data))
    

    val captor = argumentCaptor<Flux<CustomClass>>()
    verify(mockedProvider, times(0)).whatIWouldLikeToCapture(captor.capture())
    
    val result = provider.save(data);
    
    System.out.println(captor.allValues) // print: []
    StepVerifier.create(result).expectNextCount(1).verifyComplete()
}
```

```kotlin
@Component
class BazProvider(
    private val barRepository: BarRepository,
    private val fooProvider: FooProvider,
) {
    fun save(data: Data): Mono<Data> {
        return fooProvider.whatIWouldLikeToCapture(privateMethod(data))
            .then(barRepository.save(data))
    }
    
    private fun privateMethod(data: Data): Flux<CustomClass> {
        return mockedProvider.method(data).map { /* code */ }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why `times(0)` in `verify(mockedProvider, times(0)).whatIWouldLikeToCapture(captor.capture())`

I'm not an expert in mocks, but the `verify` call happens before `provider.save(data)`, so I would expect that no call happened *yet*, and thus the `captor` gets nothing at this moment.

Try moving the `verify()` below the `save()` call.